# How to use easy_localization in a dependent flutter package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using easy_localization in my app and all is working fine.
However, one of the packages my app depends on (internal package) has also translations and I would like to use easy_translation in this package.
How can I configure my main app and package so they both have their own translations?

Here is the configuration of my main app:

```
  EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: AppConfig.SUPPORTED_LANG.split(',').map((e) => Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: e)).toList(),
    path: 'lib/resources/assets/translations',
    useOnlyLangCode: true,
    assetLoader: CodegenLoader(),
    startLocale: Locale(Intl.getCurrentLocale()),
    fallbackLocale: Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: AppConfig.DEFAULT_LANG),
    child: MyApp(),
  ),
```

All the translations of my main app are inside the CodegenLoader class. I would like to do the same for my package.

Regards

Comment: did you somehow solve this?

Comment: I didn't use that package. Just a simple LocalizationsDelegate with intl.

Comment: Yeah, I will probably do the same in the future. For now, I have a hacky workaround. I'll post it as an answer since it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I think this is not possible. But there is a workaround that might help some people:

1. Add `easy_localization` to the `pubspec.yaml` of your *package*
2. Use the tr() function as you normally would inside the package code
3. Add the translation keys you are using in the *package* to the the translation file of your *main app*

   - Example: If you're using the translation key `welcome` in your package, add `"welcome": "Welcome to the App!"` to the `en.json` of your main app

Of course, this is hacky and it does not work if the main app is not using `easy_localization` but maybe it until a better solution is found.